# How to make sure nested header are selected when parent header is selected-Extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

Trying to select all the nested header when i am selecting parent header.

1. By default parent 1 and parent 2 both the column fields and nested fields are selected(Fine for me)
2. When i unselect parent 1 its nested fields also gets unselected(Fine for me)
3. When i select parent1 i am not able to select nested fields automatically(Need help here)

link:
[Nested header Fiddle code](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2oo5)

Comment: When you click on a column header it get sorted. What do you mean by selecting and unselecting columns?

Comment: @scebotariby  when you select parent 1 (as per fiddle) both nested  header wont get selected (name and mail)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with ExtJS 4.2 grid. This happens when column has `items` config (you have one `textfield` in `Parent 1` column). 
My solution was to implement a `show` listener for columns with items and show all child columns. It was a workaround, but it worked for me:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columnLines: true,
    enableLocking: true,
    columns: [{
        text: 'Parent 1',
        listeners: {
            show: function(c) {
                for (i = 0; i < c.items.length; i++) {
                    c.items.items[i].show();
                }                               
            }   
        },
        columns: [{
            text: 'Name',
            width: 100,
            sortable: true,
            lockable: true,
            dataIndex: 'name',
            items: {
                xtype: 'textfield'
            }
        }, {
            text: 'Email',
            width: 100,
            lockable: true,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'email'
        }]
    }, {
        text: 'Parent 2',
        columns: [{
            text: 'Name',
            width: 100,
            sortable: true,
            lockable: true,
            dataIndex: 'name'
        }, {
            text: 'Email',
            width: 100,
            lockable: true,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'email'
        }]
    }],
    height: 350,
    width: 600,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: This can be implemented for both parent 1 and 2 right

Comment: @JMR Yes, implement listener for every column, which has items, or use `columnshow` listener for grid.

Comment: This was the demo i did ....actually in my live project  when i unselect and select  any one nested field it was not selecting parent field as well...need to double tap the checkbox

Comment: what if there is no.....
 items: {
                xtype: 'textfield'
            }